# Blog post comment reply

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I have the following SQL Server db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [BlogEntries] 
(
          [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        , [Header] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL
        , [HeaderUrl] nvarchar(160) NOT NULL
        , [Author] nvarchar(100) NULL
        , [ShortContent] nvarchar(1500) NOT NULL
        , [Content] nvarchar(MAX) NULL
        , [Visits] int NOT NULL
        , [Visible] bit NOT NULL
        , [PublishDate] datetime NOT NULL
        , [Created] datetime NOT NULL
        , [Modified] datetime NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [BlogEntryComments] 
(
          [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        , [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
        , [Comment] nvarchar(2500) NOT NULL
        , [Email] nvarchar(50) NULL
        , [Homepage] nvarchar(100) NULL
        , [AdminPost] bit NOT NULL
        , [BlogEntryId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        , [Created] datetime NOT NULL
        , [Modified] datetime NULL
);
GO

ALTER TABLE [BlogEntries] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BlogEntries] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
GO

ALTER TABLE [BlogEntryComments] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BlogEntryComments] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
GO

ALTER TABLE [BlogEntryComments] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BlogEntryComments_dbo.BlogEntries_BlogEntryId] 
  FOREIGN KEY ([BlogEntryId]) REFERENCES [BlogEntries]([Id]) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO
```

I need to implement a reply schema to my current db. Basically a user should be able to reply to a comment and that reply should be connected to that specific comment to which has been replyed.

How should I do it?

I thought to add another field in the BlogEntryComments called `ParentComment` for example and there add the Id of the parent comment to which the reply was made? Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to ask.   What is a replay?

Comment: Replay = comment made to a comment

Comment: heh Replay means to watch or listen to something again. A comment to a comment is a Reply.

Comment: Reply ... sorry i'm not native english speaker

Comment: Also, while I don't like using guids as primary keys they can be acceptable but yours is also the clustered index. This is VERY bad. You will experience unbelievably high index fragmentation with this approach. If at all possible put a clustered index on another column.

Comment: @SeanLange: Can you please try to explain what you mean? Will it gonna be bad if I add another field to the Comments called `ParentComment` in order to build the parent child hierarchy?

Comment: @DavidDury think of a student list that is sorted by the last name. If I want to add "Zuckerberg, Mark" to the list, chances are that I only need to write one extra line to the end of the list. Now if I want to add "Musk, Elon" I will have to erase the bottom half of the list, add the new name, and rewrite all the old names. Unique identifiers are random, they will split your list into two with every new row inserted. That's why you shouldn't use them as IDs.

Comment: So basically I should add another table and that will be something like this: `Replies` and columns `ReplyId`, `Id`, `Message` where the `Id` is the `Id` of the `Comment` from the `BlogEntryComments` table. And `Replies` primary key is composite `ReplayId+Id` ?

Comment: Adding ParentComment isn't necessarily bad. The fact that you are using a guid as your clustered index however is. For one thing a guid is 4 times the storage size of an int and debugging with them is a PITA. When you use a guid as your clustered index you will hit over 99% fragmentation with as few as 5-6 thousand rows. Unless there is a valid reason for using a guid I would avoid them. And always avoid them being your clustered index.